# Can I use a jade variable as part of an object identifier within Angular curly braces?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

Sorry for the awful title!!!

I have this logic in an Angular controller...

```
$scope.fooMyText = function(text) {
  return "foo " + text;
};

$scope.txt = {
  one: "this text",
  two: "that taxt"
};
```

Using the following in a jade template works fine...

```
h1
  |{{fooMyText(txt.one)}}
```

But the following does not...

```
identifier= txt
h1
  |{{fooMyText(#{identifier}.one)}}
```

Is there a way to use a jade variable as part of the name of an object for use in Angular?

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/poYFriS5JwCI4aSAk9zP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your template from `{{fooMyText(#{identifier}.one)}}` to `|{{fooMyText(#{identifier}['one'])}}`

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wb1IjM3IDPI1A5tpxB2i?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but in the example you've linked to I want it to say "foo this text"...